# How to get doorbell louder?

Tags: doorbell

My mom has a Nutone wired doorbell but is finding it is not quite loud enough when she is in some parts of the house far away from the bell.  I looked at the doorbell and it seems to be functioning properly and has directions that say **not** to oil the plungers.  There are two plungers with springs that get activated by the front or rear doorbell button being pressed.  The current Nutone box with the plungers has two toned bars on opposite ends of the plungers so that one door gives one tone and the other door gives two tones.  There are some other directions which I cannot read about maintenance due to some paint which I wonder what they state.

I'm wondering how we might get a bit louder doorbell?  Would there be maintenance to perform that would help with volume?  Ideally we would keep the existing bell since it is pretty well built into the wall and not easily replaced.  If required, we could put a new one on top of the old one that is flushly embedded into the wall.

Comment: If there are slots or other openings in the cover, make sure they are not covered with paint -- covering the holes will dampen the sound even if they are small openings to begin with.

Comment: A picture of the bell might be helpful.

Comment: Depending on the setup, it might be possible to add a secondary bell in a different location. Wireless bells might also be an option. It might also be worth looking into bells designed specifically for the hearing impaired, which offer louder tones, flashing lights, and other attention getting gizmos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Dust off the tone bars.  Loose debris dampens their vibration.
2. Check the tone bar mounts and positioning.  If a bar is crooked or out of position, it won't ring as well.
3. Check the hammers on the solenoids.  If there is debris, clean it off.  If they have dried out or cracked, remove the hammer.  That will definitely increase the volume.